# Android Studio : E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android-recyclerview

I've found only a few articles related to this issue on StackOverflow tried all of their solutions in various combinations but can't get the `RecyclerView` to display my `RecyclerView.Adapter` that is populated with data which a I can verify and see the list in debug mode but it simply won't show the information.

My code (I struggled to paste the XML Layout files):

```
public class RecipeDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecipeModel mRecipe;
    private ArrayList<IngredientModel> mIngredientList = new ArrayList<>();
    private IngredientListAdapter ingredientListAdapter;
    private RecyclerView rvIngredientList;
    private boolean mTwoPane;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_detail);

        rvIngredientList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_ingredient_list);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rvIngredientList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        SampleRecycler sampleRecycler = new SampleRecycler(); // empty RecyclerView.Adapter
        rvIngredientList.setAdapter(sampleRecycler);

        mRecipe = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("com.wernerraubenheimer.bakingapp.data.RecipeModel");

        mIngredientList = mRecipe.getIngredients();
        ingredientListAdapter = new IngredientListAdapter(mIngredientList);
        ingredientListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // Up until this point the RecyclerVie.Adapter is populated with data - debug mode I can see the list
        rvIngredientList.swapAdapter(ingredientListAdapter, false);
    }
}

public class IngredientListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IngredientListAdapter.IngredientViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<IngredientModel> mIngredientList;
    private Context mContext;
    private boolean mTwoPane;

    public IngredientListAdapter(ArrayList<IngredientModel> ingredientList) {
        mIngredientList = ingredientList;
    }

    @Override
    public IngredientViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        mContext = parent.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.ingredient_list_item;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        boolean attachImmediatelyToParent = false;

        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, parent, attachImmediatelyToParent);
        IngredientViewHolder viewHolder = new IngredientViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(IngredientViewHolder holder, int position) {
        IngredientModel ingredient = mIngredientList.get(position);
        holder.bind(mContext, ingredient);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mIngredientList != null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return mIngredientList.size();
        }
    }

    static class IngredientViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private CardView cardviewContainer;
        private TextView tvIngredientName;
        private TextView tvIngredientQuantity;
        private TextView tvIngredientMeasure;
        private Context mContext;
        private IngredientModel mIngredient;

        IngredientViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //cardviewContainer = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_ingredient);
            tvIngredientName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_ingredient_name);
            tvIngredientQuantity =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_quantity);
            tvIngredientMeasure = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_measure);
        }

        void bind(Context context, IngredientModel ingredientModel) {
            mContext = context;
            mIngredient = ingredientModel;

            tvIngredientName.setText(mIngredient.getIngredient());
            tvIngredientQuantity.setText(mIngredient.getQuantity());
            tvIngredientMeasure.setText(mIngredient.getMeasure());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, it is difficult to decipher from the code you have pasted,
it looks like the problem is with the following function:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mIngredientList != null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return mIngredientList.size();
    }
}
```

Changing condition to `if (mIngredientList == null) {` should solve the problem.

Also, in the `RecipeDetailActivity.onCreate()` method, only following code should be enough to display the list:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_detail);
    rvIngredientList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_ingredient_list);
    rvIngredientList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mRecipe = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("com.wernerraubenheimer.bakingapp.data.RecipeModel");
    mIngredientList = mRecipe.getIngredients();

    ingredientListAdapter = new IngredientListAdapter(mIngredientList);
    rvIngredientList.setAdapter(ingredientListAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was such a silly mistake. But only one item shows. I'll work on it some more.